# How to make the following piece of code work by using template or inheritance?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, inheritance, c++14

My question is about how to define the member function **f1** to make the code work

```
#include <iostream>
struct func2{
    int a=3;

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>           
        void f1(T1 _t1, T2 _t2, T3 _t3){
            std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<_t1<<"\t"<<_t2<<"\t"<<_t3<<std::endl;
        }


    template<typename F1, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
        void f2(F1 _f1, T1 _t1, T2 _t2, T3 _t3){
            _f1(_t1, _t2, _t3);
            _f1(_t2, _t1, _t3);
            _f1(_t3, _t2, _t1);
        }

    void f3(){
        int a =1; 
        double b = 2.0;
        std::string c = "hello";
        f2(f1,a,b,c);
    };
};

int main(){       
    func2().f3(); 
}
```

Or, maybe I need to change **f2** and **F1** also. But, the requirement is to keep **f3** as it is because I can use **f2(f1_another,a,b,c)** later, and not move **f1** and **f2** out of **func2** because of their dependence on **a**. The code is just a simple model of the problem I am facing right now. Any suggestions or references are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Comment: `f2([this](auto&&... t){ f1(decltype(t)(t)...); },a,b,c);`

Comment: wouldn't it better to add std::forward? Not sure about syntax though: ```std::forward<decltype(t)>(t)...```

Comment: While you can't capture multiple overloads (without a lambda of course), you might take std::any or ... as your arguments, or pass in the permutation.

Answer (score 2):

How about this?:

```
#include <iostream>

struct func2{
    int a=3;

    struct f1
    {
        const func2* m_this;
        f1(const func2* this_)
        : m_this( this_ )
        {
        }
        template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>           
        void operator()(T1 _t1, T2 _t2, T3 _t3){
            std::cout<<m_this->a<<"\t"<<_t1<<"\t"<<_t2<<"\t"<<_t3<<std::endl;
        }
    };

    template<typename F1, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    void f2(F1 _f1, T1 _t1, T2 _t2, T3 _t3){
        _f1(_t1, _t2, _t3);
        _f1(_t2, _t1, _t3);
        _f1(_t3, _t2, _t1);
    }

    void f3(){
        int a =1; 
        double b = 2.0;
        std::string c = "hello";
        f2(f1(this),a,b,c);// The goal is to get flexibility by modifying this line
    };
};

int main(){       
    func2().f3(); 
}
```

A different approach is to wrap the templated member function and pass the wrapper template:

```
#include <iostream>

struct func2{
    int a=3;

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>           
    void f1(T1 _t1, T2 _t2, T3 _t3){
        std::cout<<a<<"\t"<<_t1<<"\t"<<_t2<<"\t"<<_t3<<std::endl;
    }

    template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
    struct f1wrap
    {
        static constexpr decltype(&func2::f1<T1, T2, T3>) value = &func2::f1<T1, T2, T3>;
    };

    template<template<typename, typename, typename> typename F1, typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
        void f2(T1 _t1, T2 _t2, T3 _t3){
            (this->*(F1<T1, T2, T3>::value))(_t1, _t2, _t3);
            (this->*(F1<T2, T1, T3>::value))(_t2, _t1, _t3);
            (this->*(F1<T3, T2, T1>::value))(_t3, _t2, _t1);
        }

    void f3(){
        int a =1; 
        double b = 2.0;
        std::string c = "hello";
        f2<f1wrap>(a,b,c);// The goal is to get flexibility by modifying this line
    };
};

int main(){       
    func2().f3(); 
}
```

You might make a macro to create f1wrap from f1 (taking advantage of template parameter packs) if you use this functorless approach extensively.

Comment: Let me know if it qualifies.. if it doesn't, I'll delete it.

Comment: The first way is what i thought. But, I don't like it because there are many common variables like **a**. I prefer the 2nd way although we need to create many wrappers for different functions like **f1**. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I'd suggest using a macro to generate f1wrap from f1 (for arbitrary argument count). Since it's a struct, you don't really need to put it in func2 scope, you might put it to f3()'s local scope as well.